# WNA3100 not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

I realize that at first this seems like the question has been asked many times over, but after having read through all of the solutions I have found that none of them work.

I just booted ubuntu 18.04 onto a new PC, and inserted the internet adapter usb stick (WNA3100). After installing the driver through ndiswrapper, the command

```
ndiswrapper -l
```

gives the following:

```
bcmwlhigh5 : driver installed
device (0846:9020) present
```

Nevertheless, ubuntu doesn't see the device and says that there is no network adapter found and

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

gives

```
  *-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: enp3s0
   version: 15
   serial: 4c:ed:fb:3f:0b:8f
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.11 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:33 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:f7504000-f7504fff memory:f7500000-f7503fff
```

or in other words not even a hint at the WNA3100 WIFI adapter.

Comment: My opinon hasn't changed at all since I posted this: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2264020&highlight=9020